# Error establishing database connection in WordPress install

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, installation

I am working with a managed server from 1&1 and I am trying to manually install WordPress with no luck. I went and downloaded the WP core files, uploaded them via FTP and then went into mySQL and created the database and username/password etc. and assigned the privileges. When I try to install wordpress via `"www.example.com/wp-admin/install.php`", I continuously receive the error:

> Error establishing a database connection

I tried everything and triple checked my user,password, etc.

Here is my credentials (Password is hidden):

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you give us a little more info about what you are using as the connection params (blank out the password of course).

Comment: did you try and delete the wp_config file? and let wp write that for u?

Comment: yeah i tried deleting and letting it write it but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ** MySQL settings ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'yourdb');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'yourdb user');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'yourpassword');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'hostname');
```

Host name is always a localhost. for check your database credential  is correct or not please feel a wrong value @ let me know I am here

Comment: Dan Hastings@ on debugger from  wp-config.php   "define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );
"

Comment: sanjay i tried everything you said but i still get this error.

Comment: Tom@ok do not worry . www.yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php , yourwebiste.com will be your domain name , please try this

Comment: tried that it brings up the same error message. i also added this to the wp-config file define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );

Comment: i do have my wordpress files in a sub folder but that shouldnt matter as long as i include the right path correct?

Comment: Tom@ please create a New database and set a all privilege for user, @

Comment: sanjay@ im going to reinstall the wordpress core files first and then recreate a new database ill let you know thanks

Comment: Tom@ please create a New database and set a all privilege for user, @

Comment: sanjay@ i created a new db and reinstalled everything still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost as the db host. Had the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Comment: go to the database and try to log in as the user you are using. see if you can create a table in the database you are trying to get wordpress to. The user might be valid and so is the db and host, but the user might not have access

Comment: Dan Hastings it let me create a table with no issues.

Comment: Dan hastings do i put 127.0.0.1 in the wp-config and the value in the user options for the db for the host name as well?